# How to remove points from values in query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a query that works great. All numeric values have format Numeric(18,8). I'm using ETL to load the data from this query and it doesn't work. The reason is that some values are shown as '0.60666666'. The error code is 1207.Invalid digit, Value '.', Pos 4, Type: Integer. Those values that have "." are calculated as a proportion. First I calculate percentage in a subquery as:

```
SELECT(t1.num::NUMERIC(18,8)/t1.den::NUMERIC(18,8))::NUMERIC(18,8) as percentage
```

This is the moment where I see those "." first time in values.

And then I multiply this percentage by volume as:

```
(t2.palletized_percentage::NUMERIC(18,8)*v.vol::NUMERIC(18,8))::NUMERIC(18,8) as volume
```

The table where I load it has this format:

```
CREATE TABLE table.volume
(
time_period DATE ENCODE zstd,
region VARCHAR(90) ENCODE zstd,
volume NUMERIC(25, 8) ENCODE zstd
)
DISTSTYLE EVEN
SORTKEY
(
time_period
);
```

How can I remove those "." that don't let me load the table? Can't use CAST because I calculate percentage so it can't be rounded.

Thank you!

Comment: @Dbloch can you please look at it? I saw you answered similar question. You suggested to CAST it but what if I need all 8 decimals?

Comment: hi if i understood question correctly issue is with decimal point after calculation ... if yes then you can cast